# Minimum of a cubic form

Tags: linear-algebra

How to minimize the cubic form $a x_1^3 + b x_1^2 x_2 + c x_1 x_2^2 + dx_2^3$ with respect to $x = (x_1,x_2)$ under the constrain $\|x\|=1$?

Comment: Did you try Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: I have tried... I was rather thinking to write the cubic form as $\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
c & d \end{array} \right) (x_1,x_2)^T \cdot (x_1^2,x_2^2) ^T$ and to get something from this...